ubuntu 24.04 support k8s version
which minimum version kubernetes  support ubuntu 24.04?

https://snapcraft.io/k8s  is available for all supported Ubuntu releases.

The Kubernetes project maintains release branches for the most recent three minor releases (1.30, 1.29, 1.28). Kubernetes 1.19 and newer receive approximately 1 year of patch support. source
Partial results of snap find k8s and snap find kubectl in Ubuntu 24.04:
k8s             v1.30.2        canonical✓  Canonical Kubernetes, a K8s distribution by Canonical
microk8s        v1.29.4        canonical✓  Kubernetes for workstations and appliances
kubectl          1.29.6        canonical✓  Command line client for controlling a Kubernetes cluster.

